# How to import the Wordpress publications into the static page?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am using in my Wordpress-based site a specific template that has no options display publications, but only static pages. How can I import it to my latest publication?

Comment: You're going to need to specify what you mean by 'Publication' - do you mean posts?

Comment: Do people even try and google anything anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest posts by entering "the Loop" enviroment, the code below is from the Twenty Eleven: Main Index Template by Wordpress

```
       <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
```

you may not want to use `twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' );` nor `twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' );` while using other template (say not based on Twenty Eleven)